# Why isn't VirtualBox working for me?

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, virtualization

Why isn't VirtualBox running virtual machines for me?

I have tried Microsoft XP, Vista, 7, 8 and Mac OS X all of which have failed to run for me. That is they 'start' when I send the command to start but then they abort or just fail to continue running immediately after I've started them.

My Host OS is 12.10.

Comment: How did you create your VMs?

Comment: I just followed the steps given by the New Virtual Machine Wizard.

Comment: Which version are you using? Are you using the version in the Ubuntu software-center or the more recent one from the VirtualBox website?

Comment: The most recent one on the website.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of BIOS do you have? Do you get any errors?

It is possible that you need to enable virtualization technology in your BIOS. For example: in my ASUS EFI BIOS i had to enable "Intel Virtualization Technology" in "Advanced" tab before VirtualBox could work.

Comment: BIOS, what's BIOS? Do elaborate.

Comment: The thing that loads before the OS. with logo of your motherboard's manufacturer and words "press DEL to enter the BIOS" (or something similar) in the bottom part of the screen.

Comment: It doesn't even show up, that's how 'immediately after' it fails.

Comment: No no, i mean when you boot your computer, not virtual machine in virtualbox.

Comment: And still, don't you really have any errors?

Comment: How the flip do I get into BIOS? When I started by Dell Vostro 3500 it rebooted without me seeing anything but: a booting screen which looked like what I would think a BIOS would be but it went so fast I don't really know how I'm meant to do anything about it and then I went into GNU GRUB and then into Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey, sorry, didn't notice your message before. I've googled about your BIOS and i think you need to press F2 when you see the DELL logo (google suggests repeatedly pressing the key while booting) or it could be the DEL key: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm

Comment: neither have worked for me, unfortunately.

Comment: So you couldn't get into BIOS? Or your virtualbox still doesn't work?

Comment: couldn't get into BIOS. It slowed down a bit when I pressed F2 and Del and I thought it was working but then it showed the GNU GRUB Window.

Comment: Well, according to this manual: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-3500_service%20manual_en-us.pdf
1. Turn on (or restart) your computer.
2. When the blue DELL™ logo is displayed, you must watch for the F2 prompt to appear. 
3. Once this F2 prompt appears, press <F2> immediately

Comment: And according to this manual your computer has "Intel® Virtualization Technology", which is disabled by default. And i guess this is your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried that all but I have A10 BIOS and I searched far and wide for a virtualisation option and it didn't have it. My laptop is just three years old but it seems to not have virtualisation capabilities.